# Conditional query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, conditional-statements

I'm relatively new to ElasticSearch and I need some advice.
After several tries, i did not found the solution and that's why I need you.

I want to make a conditional query based on the document content.

Let me explain, I have those documents in ES:

```
{
   "name": "Product n°1",
   "type": "Mail",
   "sub": "Letter"
},
{
   "name": "Product n°2",
   "type": "Video",
   "sub": null
},
{
   "name": "Product n°3",
   "type": "Mail",
   "sub": "Postcard"
}
```

The user can filter by types and sub with checkboxes (so, the user can search more than one type and sub at the same time)

**Edited**

Customers can selects with checkbox the types of the products they want to get from ES (For ex: Video, Image, Mail), they can select all of them.

The "Document" type has 4 sub-types: Letter, Postal Card, Paper, Printed and they can select which sub type they want to retrieve too.

So, we admit a customer selected Video and Mail, and Letter as sub-type of Mail.

I want to ES returns all of the documents within the selected types AND just the Letters when the document is a "Mail" type.

Sorry for my mistakes, I'm very new to ES.

Thanks to all of you trying to help !

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here's my query with Andrei Stefan's solution

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": []
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "type": [
                  "Video",
                  "Mail"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": Mail
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "sub": [
                        "Letters"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES returns all of documents of type Video and Mail, it does not apply the fillter Letters when the type is Mail.

Comment: Can you rephrase or provide more details on "I want to make a conditional query like that : I want to retrieve the products having 1, or 2 in type but if the document has a type 1 let I want to retrieve only the documents having 2 in sub."?

Comment: I sure can. Sorry for my english by the way. Not my native language.

Comment: Ok, I tried to make myself clear, I hope you'll understand.

Comment: I would try this: `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            // ['type' => $types]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  // 'type' => 2
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  // 'sub' => [1]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I don't know what you used to write that pseudo-query, so I gave you the JSON representation of what I think it would work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, I'm using PHP. I'm going to try your method and come back to you as soon as I know if it works or not ! Thanks

Comment: Ok, I updated my post to let you know what happened

Comment: Remove `"Mail"` from `"terms": {
                "type": [
                  "Video",
                  "Mail"
                ]
              }`

Comment: Ok did, now only document with type = 1 are retrieved.

Comment: `"sub"` should be "Letters" or "Letter"?

Comment: Ok was my mystake on the last post. To JSON to PHP Array was a bit buggy and did not work well. Now everything is fine. A BIG thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thousand tanks to @Andrei Stefan. The difference between update 2 is I had to delete "Mail" from the first "should" query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": []
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "type": [
                  "Video"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": Mail
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "sub": [
                        "Letters"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```